# How to Plot a function when one of its value has a specific range?

Tags: graphing-functions

$$
Z(s) = c \cos(\sqrt{2B}s)
$$

when

$$
 0 < c < 3.65 ~~\mbox{and}~~ 0 < s < 100
$$

Can someone please help me to How to plot $Z(s)$ vs $s$?

Comment: what is the value of B?

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rnjykt48lt

Answer (score 0):

try it on "Geogebra 3D"
I have plotted yours one.
https://www.geogebra.org/3d/ypk8vzc5

how can Z be only function of s whereas c is also varying?you must have to take c as a variable then while plotting it in 3D.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a $3D$ plot if you want, but I think more useful here would be to take several values of $c$ and plot a line for each one.  I would probably take $c=0,1,2,3,3.65$  A plot is below.  You should label each line with $c$ value it represents.

[image]